# How to selected duplicated items and them delete them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find the duplicated rows and then delete.

I have three tables - the data which I need to look into is in tables `a` and `c`.

For the moment I have managed to write this query

```
select   
    a.name, a.group, a.order, c.p_id
from  
    a,
join  
    b using (p_id)
join  
    c using (p_id)
where
    c.p_id = 1
```

The results is like this:

[image: Table]

```
 name   group   order   P_id    
John    T   0   1   
Michael T   1   1   
William T   2   1   
David   QG  3   1   
Richard QG  4   1   
Joseph  QG  5   1   
Thomas  QA  6   1   
James   QS  7   1
Robert  QM  8   1
Charles QM  10  1   
Christopher T   1   1   
Daniel  T   2   1   
Matthew QG  3   1   
Anthony QG  4   1   
Mark    T   0   1   
Steven  QG  5   1   
Paul    QA  6   1   
James   QS  8   1   
Robert  QM  9   1
Joshua  QA  7   1   
Kevin   CA  13  1
```

The highlight `yellow and red rows` is what I need to get but I don't how to get the result.

So what I am trying to do is that when we have duplication `name and group and the P_id are the same`, and the `order` is different.

In my query I have used a hard-coded `p_id` but I want to check all the results not just this one.

After I generate this report I need to delete the duplication keep the one that has the lowest order.

So from the screenshot, if we get the case of red rows, the row that has (Robert, QM, 9) should be deleted

If anybody can help me, I would really appreciated it.

Thank you

Comment: Please do not post screenshots, use text. See [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for a method to create good looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html) option on the select statement.

```
select distinct on (a.name, a.group, c.p_id)      
    a.name, a.group, a.order, c.p_id
from  
    a,
join  
    b using (p_id)
join  
    c using (p_id)
where
    c.p_id = 1
order by a.name, a.group desc, c.p_id;
```

NOTE: Not Tested.

Comment: First of all as i mention i want to check all the formats and not just 1, second i want to have a report with both rows that are duplicated. Thanks anyway.